# Linux Kernel Packet Forwarding Performance

Tags: linux, performance, tcpip, forwarding, packet

I've been using a Linux box as a router for some time now. Nothing too fancy, just enabling forwarding in the kernel, turning on masquerading, and setting up iptables to poke a few holes in the firewall.

Recently a friend of mine pointed out a performance problem. Single TCP connections seem to experience very poor performance. You have to open multiple parallel TCP connections to get decent speed.

For example, I have a 10 Mbit internet connection. When I download a file from a known-fast source using something like the DownThemAll! extension for Firefox (which opens multiple parallel TCP connections) I can get it to max out my downstream bandwidth at around 1 MB/s. However, when I download the same file using the built-in download manager in Firefox (uses only a single TCP connection) it starts fast and the speed tanks until it tops out around 100 KB/s to 350 KB/s.

I've checked the internal network and it doesn't seem to have any problems. Everything goes through a 100 Mbit switch. I've also run iperf both internally (from the router to my desktop) and externally (from my desktop to a Linux box I own out on the net) and haven't seen any problems. It tops out around 1 MB/s like it should. Speedtest.net also reports 10 Mbits speeds.

The load on the Linux machine is around 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 all the time, and it's got plenty of free RAM. It's an older laptop with a Pentium M 1.6 GHz processor and 1 GB of RAM. The internal network is connected to the built in Intel NIC and the cable modem is connected to a [Netgear FA511](http://kb.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/2639) 32-bit PCMCIA network card.

I think the problem is with the packet forwarding in the router, but I honestly am not sure where the problem could be. Is there anything that would substantially slow down a single TCP stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed. There was some sort of hardware issue (still no idea what) on the machine. After installing the same Linux distro and reconfiguring the firewall and packet forwarding the same way on a different machine, I'm no longer having the problem.

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a per-stream performance issue at either the remote end or your ISP - each individual stream is being throttled, either deliberately (by your ISP) or just due to congestion (at the remote site, at your ISP, or anywhere in between).

It is unlikely to be a fault at your end.

As an example of how this works when the issue is congestion, imagine a web server with a 10000Kbyte/sec connection and no other limits/bottlenecks. If there are 100 active connections downloading large objects they'll each (ignoring variances caused by latency and congestion differences between each client and the server) get around 100Kbyte/sec on average. If you opened five connections instead of one, you would get something more like 480Kbyte/sec (10000/104*5) while each single stream gets something along the lines of 95Kbyte/sec (10000/104*1). Of course in this example you are the only one using multiple connections, which is unlikely to be the case in real life. And also this math only works if the traffic management under congestion results in a fair average rate given to each stream, again in real life there are many factors that will cause this to vary, and the traffic management may impose some per host limits on top of any explicit or implied per stream ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked that as well. We swapped in a generic Linksys router and it was not experiencing this problem. It was able to download at 10 Mbit on a single TCP stream. I've also tested downloading a file from my Linux box out on the net (which I know isn't throttled) and it experienced the same problem.

Comment: Odd. I wouldn't expect Linux to affect traffic this way unless some explicit traffic shaping is setup. If you've setup the routing/filtering/mangling rules for the masquerading and port forwarding manually then you'd know if you'd done this, but if you've used a GUI tool or script from elsewhere if might be worth verifying the contents of the active ip_tables and queueing rules to see if there is anything unexpected there.